# VueJS 2 v-for form input radio-buttons checked attribute not working

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I have no idea why this is not working. I check if the index I have reached is `0` if it is, set the input box value to checked. Otherwise, don't. It seems like a VERY simple thing to do, but I cannot fathom why this is broken?

VueJS:

```
<div class="large-6 columns">
  <h5 class="subheader">Standard templates</h5>
  <div>
    <form>
      <template v-for="(template, index) in systemTemplates">
        <input type="radio" v-bind:id="template.reportId" v-bind:value="template.reportId" v-model="selectedTemplate" v-if="index == 0" checked />
        <input type="radio" v-bind:id="template.reportId" v-bind:value="template.reportId" v-model="selectedTemplate" v-else />
        <label v-bind:for="template.reportId">{{template.title | sanitizeStr}}</label>
      </template>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Image of visual result:

[image: Result]

---

rendered DOM elements:

```html
<div class="large-6 columns">
  <h5 class="subheader">
    Standard skabeloner
  </h5>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input type="radio" id="59a92aafae7a711b3890174e" checked="checked" value="59a92aafae7a711b3890174e">
      <label for="59a92aafae7a711b3890174e">Default PDF report</label>
      <input type="radio" id="59a92aafae7a711b38901753" value="59a92aafae7a711b38901753">
      <label for="59a92aafae7a711b38901753">Default Repeater template: 2 C...</label>
      <input type="radio" id="59a92aafae7a711b38901758" value="59a92aafae7a711b38901758">
      <label for="59a92aafae7a711b38901758">Default PDF with Map</label>
      <input type="radio" id="59a92aafae7a711b38901759" value="59a92aafae7a711b38901759">
      <label for="59a92aafae7a711b38901759">Default Repeater template: 2 C...</label>
      <input type="radio" id="59a92aafae7a711b3890175f" value="59a92aafae7a711b3890175f">
      <label for="59a92aafae7a711b3890175f">Niras standard PDF</label>
      <input type="radio" id="59a92aafae7a711b38901760" value="59a92aafae7a711b38901760">
      <label for="59a92aafae7a711b38901760">Niras standard PDF m. forside</label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using radio buttons like checkboxes because you like the look of radio buttons? just wondering, because that's not how radio buttons are used :p

Comment: I am using radio buttons as a single selection option for selecting a PDF Template for a user to export their data into :)

Comment: extra note - I am not the one who developed this product :P I have become the maintainer :)

Comment: You realise that's a poor choice, since once selected, the radio button can't be cleared, since each is the only one in it's "radio group"

Comment: I really don't no :) had no idea. Do you have an example on where this could become a problem?

Comment: yes, your output html - https://jsfiddle.net/5y8hLnm0/ - try unchecking an option after it's checked

Comment: I see you point - but due to the nature of VueJS this is not a problem. I agree that this is not intended behaviour, but since the inputfield is bound to the `selectedTemplate` Vue model it switches in my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `v-model`, you should not use the `checked` attribute, but set the default value of the `v-model` to the desired checked value.

Use only one input in your loop:

```
<template v-for="(template, index) in systemTemplates">
  <input type="radio" v-bind:id="template.reportId" v-bind:value="template.reportId" v-model="selectedTemplate" />
  <label v-bind:for="template.reportId">{{template.title | sanitizeStr}}</label>
</template>
```

And set `selectedTemplate` default value to `systemTemplates[0].reportId`:

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedTemplate: this.systemTemplates[0].reportId
  }
}
```

Comment: Bloody hell mate - thank you bud! Did not realize that Vue have chosed to ignore some HTML5 features.

Comment: Glad it helped :)